# Rewrite rule for url that's different than directory structure

Tags: htaccess

We have a a site that has a url like such:

```
http://www.example.com/sample
```

Internally on the server the directory structure is like this:

```
/site-specific/www.example.com/sample
```

The htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sample/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site-specific/%{HTTP_HOST}/sample
```

If I visit `http://www.example.com/site-specific/www.example.com/sample` I can get to the content.  But visiting `www.example.com/sample` leads to a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing this? This does not make sense to me. Your path /site-specific/www.example.com should not enter the picture at all that I can see. Without telling us the same thing, can you tell us the problem you are trying to solve?? What started you on this path?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `/sample` because your pattern is expecting `/sample/` (with a trailing slash).

However, if you simply want to rewrite from one URL to the other, then all you need is:

```
RewriteRule ^(sample)$ /site-specific/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

The captured groups (ie. `(.*)`) in your original code would seem to be unnecessary. (?) The captured group above and the `$1` is simply to avoid you having to retype "sample" in the substitution.

Comment: The entirety of the rule is from when it was hosted on another site.  We switched hosts and changes directory structure a bit.  I'll try your answer first thing in the morning.  Thanks!